# Why can I not retrieve single element from ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

I have an array with coefficients from a  linear regression

```
# create linear regression object
reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()

# train the model using the training sets
reg.fit(X_train, y_train)

Coef=reg.coef_
```

I want to access a single coefficient one at a time, I am trying to use

```
Coef[0]
```

But weirdly it returns me the whole list of coefficients and not just the first value.
For example, `Coef[0]` returns:

```
array([-150902.34221607,  283378.84215229,  378924.08907523,
        468388.57798762, -533007.41951712, 1916050.4990389 ,
       1027672.54806697,  479101.17362007, 1868868.23957094,
       3863354.1571093 ])
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Possibly your array has two dimensions, and the output you get is a one-dimensional array that is the first entry in a two-dimensional one.

Comment: @Schnitte Coef.shape gives me (1, 10)

Comment: That explains it. shape (1, 10) means the array is in fact two-dimensional, only that it has, in one of these dimensions, one entry composed of ten entries. If you print the overall array Coef, rather than Coef[0], you'll see that from the extra pair of parentheses.

Comment: You can reshape your array with `Coef.reshape(Coef.shape[1])` (this works on `(1,n)` arrays and gives an error on `(m,n)` arrays where `m!=1`   makes no sense).